# Nodejs get result from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

i'm tryna get my array of results out of the callback method, the array is containing all of those things i want in but i can use it outside of the functions always keep undefined result. I was looking on many website for helping me to improve it but no results.

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var fs = require('fs');
var Initializer = require('./Initializer');
var StaticRoomList = Initializer.getStaticRoomList(fs, DOMParser);
console.log(StaticRoomList);

openRoomListXML = function(fs, DOMParser, callback){
try{
    fs.readFile('./XML/RoomList.xml', function(e, data){
        if(e){
            callback(e);
        }
        else{
            var BuffertoXMLString = String(data);
            var XMLOutput = new DOMParser().parseFromString(BuffertoXMLString, "text/xml");
            var XMLDocument = XMLOutput.documentElement;
            callback(null, XMLDocument);
        }

    });

}
catch(fsException){
    console.log(fsException);
}
};

getStaticRoomList = function(fs, DOMParser){
openRoomListXML(fs, DOMParser, function readList(e, XMLDocument){
    if(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    else{
        var nodeList = XMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("room");
        var arrayRoomList = [];
        for(i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++){
            arrayRoomList.push(nodeList[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
        return arrayRoomList;
    }
});
};


 exports.getStaticRoomList = getStaticRoomList;
```

Comment: *"i'm tryna"* = "I'm trying to".

Comment: `getStaticRoomList` doesn't return anything

Comment: I expect this is another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321 — but it's really unclear what function you are talking about and what value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticRoomList` doesn't return anything since the code inside the callback function is executed long after the function is terminated. You should define another callback function for `getStaticRoomList`too.

So in the end, to obtain the array you will do something like

```
var StaticRoomList;
Initializer.getStaticRoomList(fs, DOMParser,function(result){
   StaticRoomList = result;
});
```

And in the callback inside `getStaticRoomList`, instead of trying to return the result, you simply call the callback function of `getStaticRoomList`

Comment: even with it StaticRoomList stay undefined outside the function and stay good inside.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JS are async.

You have to pass a callback function as a parameter.

Below there is an example:

```
    getStaticRoomList = function(fs, DOMParser, callBack){
openRoomListXML(fs, DOMParser, function readList(e, XMLDocument){
    if(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    else{
        var nodeList = XMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("room");
        var arrayRoomList = [];
        for(i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++){
            arrayRoomList.push(nodeList[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
        callBack(arrayRoomList);
    }
});

getStaticRoomList(fs, DOMParser, function(error, result){
    if(error != null){
        //Deal with resul
    }
})
```